# Using guice with custom data source

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Let's say I have a nontrivial tree of dependencies between classes. There are no cycles, but it goes several levels deep. At the very bottom there is a hibernate `Session`.

```
MyService -> MyDao -> Session
MyService -> MyCollaborator -> AnotherCollaborator
MyCollaborator -> MyDao
AnotherCollaborator -> MyDao
AnotherCollaborator -> AnotherDao -> Session
```

You get the point.

I would like to create the `Session` manually outside Guice and then use Guice to generate the entire graph from `MyService` down, using this `Session`. How can I do it?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Provider](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings)?

**EDIT**

A provider is a user-defined factory that can be declared to guice when making bindings.

It allows the user to inject unspecified numbers of instances (by injecting the provider itself and invoking manually) or to supply interesting creation behavior, such as creating needed side-effects not carried out by the type's own constructor.

It's therefore a convenient tool for marrying other 3rd-party APIs into your dependencies: create a provider for each desired type and have it do whatever setup is required.

Concretely they are a generic interface providing a single `get()` method, templated on the type you wish to manually create inside.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? I saw that example and it's close to mine, with one exception: `Connection` or `Session` is unknown to Guice.

Comment: For this to work, I would need to somehow feed the provider with my `Session` from outside Guice. Can you please provide concrete example of that?

Comment: Ah.  If you have a specific instance, you could shove it into a static member or thread local somewhere, and retrive it in the provider.  This somewhat defeats the point though; could you move the `Session` creation code into the provider?

Comment: Alternately if you have the `Session` at binding time, you could bind it as a Singleton and dispense with global variables.

Comment: Yeah, more likely a thread-local in a singleton provider. Would that work? I have only two words to "defeating the point" - legacy code. :-)